# What is the red mist in Redbelly Mine in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I go to Shor's Stone, someone says that they saw red mist in the mine (Redbelly Mine).  When I went in there, I didn't see any red mist.  Does anyone know what they were talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go deep enough into the mine, I'm pretty sure you will eventually see the red fog near the very bottom, but it has no impact on game play, so it's easy to miss. (As @Nelson points out below, the mist apparently doesn't appear unless you are using the Unofficial Skyrim Patch; for the special edition you can get that [here](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266/?), which includes the change:

> The mine will also have modified visuals in an attempt to portray the described "red mist".

The best guess for what the red mist is, involves the nearby location of [Redwater Den](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Redwater_Den). This cave system is located near the western end of Redbelly Mine (there's a skooma lab in it). If you go deep enough into that cave system you'll eventually run into the Redwater Spring that gives all the nearby locations their name:

[image: Redwater Spring]

The most reasonable explanation is that the red mist is water vapon from the blood-red water, possibly coming from an underground waterfall, or evaporation, or whatever, that runs into the lower parts of the mine. As far as I know, the game never bothers to explain it specifically.

Comment: Ok this helps alot.  My mom and I were trying to search for other rooms in the mine, trying to find the mist they were talking about, but couldn't find any other passages, and the mist never showed up.  We got plenty of normal white mist, though!

Answer (score 4):

You don't see the mist because the official version is not displaying it correctly.

This is fixed in the Unofficial Skyrim Patch 1.2.6.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Redbelly_Mine)

Comment: Um... I'm using Skyrim Special Edition for the PS4...

Comment: Hmm.  You're suppose to be getting mod support eventually.  I don't think they fixed it for this area.

Comment: this explains why I remember seeing it, good catch :)